# Which .htaccess rules do I need for Client side routing with Create-React-App hosted within a WordPress page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, create-react-app

I've got a React app which has client side routing in place. This is hosted within a WordPress page and clientside it works a treat. However if you visit one of the child pages/routes within my app and hit reload you get some nasty WordPress errors as phycially that page doesn't actually exist on the server or within WordPress.

`/MyApp` <- is an actual WordPress page which has my React code within its template

Client side routes, all served from my app as long as you started at the above page

`/MyApp/step-1`

`/MyApp/step-2`

Hitting those urls directly causes a 404 or WordPress error. Sounds like I need a rewrite url to redirect any request for the child routes to redirect to the parent one so `/MyApp/step-1` would rewrite to `/MyApp`?

Create-react-app doc's has a section on how to do this but I'm not sure where to put it, I think WordPress' existing rewrite rules are over powering it.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

This is what they give (but no context of what to do if other existing rules are in there):

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Which .htaccess rules do I need and in what order to get this to work nicely with WordPress?

This is the content of my existing .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Tried this here but it appears to not be doing as it should? I worry the above rule is over-powering it?
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /get-a-quote/ [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm a window dev so .htaccess isn't my natural habitat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to power through this one, for anyone who lands on this and needs it here is what I came up with:

```
# This is our stuff to handle our nested React App, it has client-side routing so we need to
# catpure any "real" requests for the child pages and redirect them to the parent
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # MyApp here is the folder of my app, the url you would use to access it
  RewriteRule ^MyApp\/.+$ /MyApp/ [R,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```